# app/bootstrap.php.cache : failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: symfony

After clone project from github i got next error:

> Warning: require_once(C:\OpenServer\domains\MyBlog.test\web/../app/bootstrap.php.cache): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\OpenServer\domains\MyBlog.test\web\app_dev.php on line 20
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\OpenServer\domains\MyBlog.test\web/../app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='.;c:/openserver/modules/php/PHP-5.5;c:/openserver/modules/php/PHP-5.5/PEAR/pear') in C:\OpenServer\domains\MyBlog.test\web\app_dev.php on line 20

Unfortunately in .gitignore file i founded next note:

```
/app/bootstrap.php.cache
/var/bootstrap.php.cache
/bin/*
!bin/console
!bin/symfony_requirements
```

So, how to solve this problem?.

I execute php composer.phar update command, but it's not helped.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You probably need to run [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md) to generate the bootstrap file and download vendors.

In your composer.json you will see a build bootstrap command that gets executed for you.

```
"post-install-cmd": [
    "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap"
],
```

Comment: The command that you need to execute in order to solve the problem is `composer install`

Comment: @JoëlSalamin Before that worked for me, I had to add the var directory to extras https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony3-upgrade/new-dir-structure#moving-bootstrap-php-cache